# How to get maximum row of each group?

Tags: mysql, sql, greatest-n-per-group

I have a database in which people submit votes for people in different places. At a given time, I want to find out who has the most votes at each place. (A person can be voted at two different places)

This is the SQL I have so far:

```
SELECT placeId, userVotedId, cnt 
FROM 
    (SELECT uvo.userVotedId, p.placeId, count(*) as cnt 
     FROM users as u, users_votes as uvo, places as p 
     WHERE u.userId = uvo.userVotedId 
       AND p.placeId = uvo.placeId 
     GROUP BY userVotedId, placeId) 
AS RESULT
```

which gives me this result:

[image]

Now, these are the rows I REALLY want:

[image]

What's missing in my query so I can get this?

- I want one result per place. So I should see only distinct placeIds, with the userVotedId who received the most votes.
- In the event of a tie, a random winner will do!

Comment: what you get and what you want are identical. So, your query works!

Comment: @cha I thought the same, but the point is to eliminate the double placeid = 51. There might have been more graspable ways to point this out instead of the four bumpy red boxes ;-)

Comment: If you are trying to get the top row based on cnt once you have additionally grouped by placeID of your results, this is a harder problem than it at first appears. In SQL Server I think you can accomplish this with APPLY, but that does not supported (?) in MySQL.

Comment: Have you tested my answer -- here is the fiddle (http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/23bd7/6)?  Perhaps not the most elegant, but it works (would be nicer if MySQL supported CTEs).  Good luck!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

<strike>Seems like you need one more aggregate. Use the `MAX()` aggregate on your `cnt` value and `GROUP BY placeId, userVotedId`:</strike>

```
SELECT placeId, userVotedId, max(cnt)
FROM 
(
  SELECT uvo.userVotedId, p.placeId, count(*) as cnt 
  FROM users as u
  INNER JOIN users_votes as uvo
    ON u.userId = uvo.userVotedId 
  INNER JOIN places as p 
    ON p.placeId = uvo.placeId 
  GROUP BY userVotedId, placeId
) AS RESULT
GROUP BY placeId, userVotedId
```

*Note:* I changed your query to use `JOIN` syntax instead of the commas between the tables.

Edit, based on your comment the following should work:

```
select total.uservotedid,
  total.placeid,
  total.cnt
from
(
  SELECT uvo.userVotedId, p.placeId, count(*) as cnt 
  FROM users as u
  INNER JOIN users_votes as uvo
    ON u.userId = uvo.userVotedId 
  INNER JOIN places as p 
    ON p.placeId = uvo.placeId 
  GROUP BY userVotedId, placeId
) total
inner join
(
  select max(cnt) Mx, placeid
  from
  (
    SELECT uvo.userVotedId, p.placeId, count(*) as cnt 
    FROM users as u
    INNER JOIN users_votes as uvo
      ON u.userId = uvo.userVotedId 
    INNER JOIN places as p 
      ON p.placeId = uvo.placeId 
    GROUP BY userVotedId, placeId
  ) mx
  group by placeid
) src
  on total.placeid = src.placeid
  and total.cnt = src.mx
```

See [SQL Fiddle with Demo](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/346e1/21)

The result is:

```
| USERVOTEDID | PLACEID | CNT |
-------------------------------
|          65 |      11 |   1 |
|          67 |      13 |   1 |
|          67 |      25 |   1 |
|          67 |      51 |   2 |
```

Edit #2, if you want a random number returned if there is a tie, then you can use user variables:

```
select uservotedid,
  placeid, 
  cnt
from
(
  select total.uservotedid,
    total.placeid,
    total.cnt,
    @rownum := case when @prev = total.placeid then @rownum+1 else 1 end rownum,
    @prev := total.placeid pplaceid
  from
  (
    SELECT uvo.userVotedId, p.placeId, count(*) as cnt 
    FROM users as u
    INNER JOIN users_votes as uvo
      ON u.userId = uvo.userVotedId 
    INNER JOIN places as p 
      ON p.placeId = uvo.placeId 
    GROUP BY userVotedId, placeId
  ) total
  inner join
  (
    select max(cnt) Mx, placeid
    from
    (
      SELECT uvo.userVotedId, p.placeId, count(*) as cnt 
      FROM users as u
      INNER JOIN users_votes as uvo
        ON u.userId = uvo.userVotedId 
      INNER JOIN places as p 
        ON p.placeId = uvo.placeId 
      GROUP BY userVotedId, placeId
    ) mx
    group by placeid
  ) src
    on total.placeid = src.placeid
    and total.cnt = src.mx
  order by total.placeid, total.uservotedid
) src
where rownum = 1
order by placeid, uservotedid
```

See [SQL Fiddle with Demo](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/fd0b3/18)

Comment: Do you want the max by place only? Or do you also want the userid?

Comment: I want one result per place. So I should see only distinct placeIds, with the userVotedId who received the most votes.

Comment: @bluefeet -- looks like my answer identically :-)

Comment: @sgeddes I was not paying attention to the other answers I was working on a SQL fiddle answer.

Comment: I thought you had it, but then I added a vote and it didn't give me the right result: http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/fd0b3/1

Comment: @omegatai this gives the same result as the other answer. Are you saying that one is wrong too? -- http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/fd0b3/2  I am not sure why you say the result is wrong. When you have two `placeid`'s with the same vote count you will return both.

Comment: @bluefeet as you can see in the fiddle, there are two winners for placeId=11.

Comment: @omegatai that is the same result that the accepted answer gives.  The `max()` will return both if the vote total is the same.  This fiddle (http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/fd0b3/2) shows my answer and the accepted answer both showing two results for placeid = 11.

Comment: @omegatai what do you want to do in the event of a tie total vote?

Comment: @bluefeet a random winner will do!

Comment: @omegatai see my edit. I applied user variables to get a row number for each row. If the placeid is the same then the row number will increase. Your final product will return those rows with a row number of 1.

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT placeId, userVotedId, MAX(cnt)
    FROM (SELECT uvo.userVotedId, p.placeId, count(*) AS cnt 
          FROM users as u, users_votes as uvo, places as p 
          WHERE u.userId = uvo.userVotedId AND p.placeId = uvo.placeId 
          GROUP BY userVotedId, placeId) AS RESULT
    GROUP BY  placeId
```

- Similar Question - [SQL query max(), count()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7832768/sql-query-max-count)
- [Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/23bd7/4)

Comment: No, I tried that before (grouping by placeId at the end), but the problem is it doesn't give the right answer. Look at the result: The userVotedId of placeId=51 should be 67, yet it is 63.

Answer (score 1):

For simplicity, I called your query Test:

```
SELECT * 
FROM Test T JOIN (
SELECT t.placeId, Max(t.cnt) maxcnt
FROM Test t
GROUP BY t.placeId) T2 ON T.placeId = T2.placeId and T.cnt = T2.maxcnt
```

Here is the [Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/9ff1c/12).

BTW -- Test = :

```
SELECT uvo.userVotedId, p.placeId, count(*) as cnt 
  FROM users as u
  INNER JOIN users_votes as uvo
    ON u.userId = uvo.userVotedId 
  INNER JOIN places as p 
    ON p.placeId = uvo.placeId 
  GROUP BY userVotedId, placeId
```

Good luck.

--EDIT -- as requested, here is the final code:

```
SELECT * 
FROM (SELECT uvo.userVotedId, p.placeId, count(*) AS cnt 
          FROM users as u, users_votes as uvo, places as p 
          WHERE u.userId = uvo.userVotedId AND p.placeId = uvo.placeId 
          GROUP BY userVotedId, placeId) T JOIN (
SELECT t.placeId, Max(t.cnt) maxcnt
FROM (SELECT uvo.userVotedId, p.placeId, count(*) AS cnt 
          FROM users as u, users_votes as uvo, places as p 
          WHERE u.userId = uvo.userVotedId AND p.placeId = uvo.placeId 
          GROUP BY userVotedId, placeId) t
GROUP BY t.placeId) T2 ON T.placeId = T2.placeId and T.cnt = T2.maxcnt
```

Comment: @omegatai -- I used this demo with my SQL and it worked -- here is the fiddle: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/23bd7/6

Comment: I just realized your solution doesn't quite work. See here: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/6a8f4/1